# What is the coefficient that shows whether there is a positive or negative relationship between variables in vector error correction models?

Tags: r, interpretation, cointegration, vector-error-correction-model

I am trying to estimate the long-run and short-run relationship between variables. Based on the Johansen cointegration analysis it was concluded, that there is one cointegrating relationship. The next step of our analysis is to estimate the VECM model using the VECM function in R, but there is a problem for me. ECT shows the statistically significant relationship between variables in the long run, but what type of this relationship is it? Is it a positive or negative relationship? How can I find the estimate of variables that show me the type of relationship? Is it determined by the sign in the column rw-1 for example?
[image]

And what about a short-run relationship? Where I can find an estimates for short-run relationship?

I read a lot of manuals and watched a lot of videos but I can not find any easy explanation of this.

Lot of thanks!